# Altium Error? What is this reddish box?

Tags: altium

I've been to a couple introductory Altium trainings and everything goes fine and dandy. This is the actual first board I am working on by myself. I've been learning so much just by doing stuff myself but there is something that I can't seem to quite understand.

Whenever I transfer my schematic to the PCB is is placed inside this reddish box, I believe it is a Room. All the examples I saw during training didn't do this. And if I move the components outside the box they turn green (DRC error maybe?)

Does anyone know what this means?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wtxbh.png]

Comment: That's called a room.  It probably came from schematic.  You can uncheck the room export at the time you synchronize.

Comment: I hate, hate, hate rooms, every once in a while they keep creeping back into my designs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is indeed called a "Room".

Rooms are relevant if you're doing multi-channel design, as they let you copy the layout between channels.

It's also completely normal.

If you want to disable it, it's very easy to do:

- Click the room -> PCB Inspector panel -> uncheck "Rule Enabled" checkbox.
  [image]
- "Design" menu -> "Rules" menu item ->  In the tree: "Design Rules" -> "Placement" -> "Room Definition" -> uncheck all the "Enabled" checkboxes.
  [image]

Alternatively, you can just delete the room, but it will come back next time you synchronize the schematic to the PCB.

Comment: In Project Options (somewhere, can't remember right now), you can disable rooms for the project so they won't come back.

Comment: @dext0rb - Hmm. I hadn't noticed that. You're right! It's Project options -> Class Generation -> "Generate rooms"

Comment: Or Project options -> Comparator -> Extra Room Definitions -> Ignore

Answer (score 38):

No, this is the correct way to disable Rooms in Altium.

Go to Project -> Project Options

[image: Altium Project Options Class Generation Rooms]

In the class generation tab, you can select not to generate rooms. If your project contains multiple schematics, then you'll need to untick this box for each schematic.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; it's very straightforward.

Comment: How do I find and delete all existing rooms?

Comment: @Bryce - To delete a room, click on it, and press delete. Do this for each of the rooms.

Comment: That's assuming one can find the rooms. @Rocketmagnet

Answer (score 3):

Rooms are used for grouping components into logical areas. When working on complex projects, using rooms can make layout easier because components on a sheet of the schematic get placed into a room. This helps to make placement easier because you don't need to go hunting for all the components that you need.

Rooms are also used for multi-channel design, which allows you to design a circuit once and then instantiate multiple copies of the same circuit, including copying room layout.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the Rooms.

They have a pretty limited functionality, and are generally more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: Can you expand this answer a bit?