# Altium: can not remove or change black rectangle in panelization

Tags: altium, panelize

I have a panelized pcb in altium. Opening it, a black rectangle shows in the background, as you can see in this picture:

[image: Capture of the panelized pcb view]

The rectangle has no relation with the panelized pcb.
I want to remove it, or at least change its size, because if I print the pcb, it shows up, as you can see here:

[image: Capture of printed pdf]

I found [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42563/altium-error-what-is-this-reddish-box) and I tried to disable rooms, but it appears didn't help, so I guess it is not a room.
I also tried unchecking every item in the PCB printout properties dialog, and also tried hiding all the layers, but the rectangle is still there.

I didn't designed the pcb or its panelization, I just need to obtain a pdf for documentation and the rectangle makes the image unclear and ugly, so I'd like to remove it.

I appreciate any hint.

Thanks,

Comment: That looks like the "Board Shape". Click Design->Board Shape and you should be able to make it align to your board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is the default board set up by Altium. In order to change its size and/or shape, press the "1" key (to switch to board view) and go to Design-> Edit Board Shape as @brhans suggested. You should be able to change the shape from there. Make sure you leave some material around the outside--The manufacturer needs to be able to route out around your boards in order for them to be broken out of the panel. Generally I recommend leaving about 1/2 inch if you can. Check your manufacturer to see what board size they recommend and go from there.