# Altium room on PCB layout after ECO

Tags: altium

When I update the PCB layout from the schematic, it will place some room on the PCB editor for each sheet. How to remove this all in once ? Is there are a way to select them all in once and to delete them?

Comment: I think, what you need is [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42563/altium-error-what-is-this-reddish-box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just change your ECO generation options to not automatically create them if you're not using them:

[image]

Otherwise to remove the rooms, yes, you can just select them in the PCB Editor and delete them.

Comment: thank you. I never understood why they create a room for this.

Comment: I think the MO they assume for it is if you have components on a given sheet, they'll belong together in layout, or in multi-channel devices, it's one of the things that supports being able to easily duplicate your layout across channels.