# Room Definition error in Altium

Tags: altium, error, drc

I have placed my first BGA on a PCB. I have followed the instructions from this video:

[How to fanout a BGA - Altium Designer 16.1 - Joao Beck](https://youtu.be/jUSi4rxBhsY)

The overall footprint of the BGA is much larger than the pad area and so my room does not totally encompass the entire component footprint. Regardless, my BGA fanned out nicely.

However, now when I run my DRC, I get the following error:

> Room Definition: Between BGA Component on Top Layer And BGA_Room (Bounding Region) (All)

Note: I also removed the default room from the schematic using [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/42700/104097) method.

**What does this error mean? How do I resolve it?**

[image: BGA with room]

Comment: Just make the room big enough to fit the whole component into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rooms were used to keep components within or out of them.
If this room is not used for that, uncheck `design` > `rules` > `placement` > `room definition`.

Comment: Thank you. The room was used for the BGA fanout as per the video. I guess I can delete /disable or enlarge the room once I have done the fanout.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Don't delete the original auto-generated room. There's no reason you can't have two rooms overlapping. One to tell where to place the components, and one to use for defining rules.

Option 2: Turn off auto-generating the room for each schematic sheet, so there won't be any rule saying the BGA component has to be in a particular room.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. It appear that the BGA room is causing the DRC error (and not the deletion of the default room). If I resize the BGA room to encompass the whole component then the DRC error goes away.

Comment: Option 3: now that you've generated your fan-out, delete the room.